# pick the first result for each parameter

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with account_number, account_code and code_date
I am trying to get the latest code for each account, but the group by is giving me multiple observation for each account, thus I can't even use the first/top statement.

example:

```
account_id  Account_Attribute_Code   current_att_date
1                579                      01.01.2005
1                254                      01.02.2006
1                366                      10.10.2018
2                748                      01.07.2008
2                766                      08.05.2009
2                205                      07.06.2014
```

```sql
 SELECT 
       account_id, 
       Account_Attribute_Code,
       Max(Account_Attribute_Update_Date) AS current_att_date
 FROM my_table
 GROUP BY Account_Id, 
          Account_Attribute_Code
```

I want to have only 1 row for each account, with his attribute_code where the date is the most current.

Comment: You mentioned "top" ... are you using SQL Server?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.Account_Attribute_Update_Date = (select max(t2. Account_Attribute_Update_Date)
                                         from t t2
                                         where t2.account_id = t.account_id
                                        );
```

There are multiple approaches to this problem.  With an index on `(account_id, Account_Attribute_Update_Date)`, then this normally has the best performance.

One caveat:  If there are duplicate maximum dates for an account, you will get multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server, I would use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    account_id, Account_Attribute_Code, Account_Attribute_Update_Date
FROM my_table
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id
                       ORDER BY Account_Attribute_Update_Date DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() function

```
 SELECT 
       account_id, 
       Account_Attribute_Code,
       Account_Attribute_Update_Date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id
                       ORDER BY Account_Attribute_Update_Date DESC) as rn
 FROM my_table where rn=1
```